# pysnmp trap send status

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I want to validate if snmp trap messages send was a success or failure and log it.

So I was wondering if I check the return value of transportDispatcher.runDispatcher(), will that give any error code.

What are other options?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using synchronous [hlapi API](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/notification.html), you should inspect `errorIndication` - it will contain local SNMP errors:

```
>>> from pysnmp.hlapi import *
>>> g = sendNotification(SnmpEngine(),
...                      CommunityData('public'),
...                      UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 162)),
...                      ContextData(),
...                      'trap',
...                      NotificationType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'linkDown')))
>>> next(g)
(None, 0, 0, [])
```

Remote SNMP errors can't be communicated by the remote party because it's a unidirectional exchange.

Also, `PySnmpError` exception can potentially be raised on a hard non-SNMP error.